# Sublime Text 3: There are no packages available for installation

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I have a problem with packages installation for `Sublime Text 3`. 
I downloaded `ST3` and follow the instructions https://packagecontrol.io/installation .
I clicked Package Control —> Install Package and have [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uTYj.jpg)  ...
Sublime Console:

```
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3083 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.0935303
startup time: 0.12453
first paint time: 0.12453
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Package Control: Installing 1 missing dependency
Package Control: The dependency specified, bz2, is not available
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-01-04 17:28:04, next run at 2016-01-04 18:28:04 or after
```

P.S. — I use Windows 7 x64 and Sublime Text 3 version 3083 x64 .

Comment: As a new user, don't forget you can earn a badge by reading the Tour page: http://stackoverflow.com/tour specficially where it says, 'The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.'

Comment: @jimlohse part of the good code of conduct around here also says to not badger the OP to accept your answer, which BTW is incorrect.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your comment above, I would hope when you reference a "code of conduct" you would kindly provide a link to that code. Meta questions like this suggest it's a fine line: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer I know when I only had a 1 rep on SO I didn't realize I could accept answers, so I felt I was being educational. So when I delete my answer now, perhaps you will point to something on SO that defines my behavior as "badger"ing,  per, "It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil..."

Comment: A couple more things, I didn't think discussions like this were appropriate in comments or elsewhere, but I defer to your experience. I wasn't "badger"ing to accept my answer, but the best answer. Look at the top answer here:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat " Encouraging them to accept a good answer (even your own) is just teaching them the right way to use the system." Would be happy to delete these comments but please educate me thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not only you, it is a general downtime thing, I don't know why it is like that and in general I am very disappointed that they don't continue updating and moving on from beta version of Sublime Text 3(beta for two years by this month), it seems that Sublime Text is dying and it is my favorite text editor.

UPDATE: It seems like there is a fix using an archived version of the package control list, however, as Patik commented: "This lists and installs older versions of the packages. It grabs versions from July 2015 or earlier (when the archive.org copy of the JSON file was made, I guess). Even if you try to upgrade a package you will not get a newer one unless you bypass Package Control and install the package manually."

You would need to add the following:
"channels":
[
"https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json",
"https://web.archive.org/web/20150905194312/https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json"
]

to the JSON that is found in the menu under: Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User

As written by MattDMo, apparently the hosting company for Package Control was under a DDoS attack and therefore there was the downtime, everything seems in order right now so I will suggest to remove the channels from the Settings - User JSON underneath Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User

Please check out his answer if you want to find more information regarding the attack and wbond.

Comment: Package Control's being down has **nothing** to do with the slow pace of development on ST3. An answer here is no place to bitch about whether the author's development schedule agrees with yours.

Comment: Thanks.. I recently Sublime Text 3, but I really like it. I hope it will continue to evolve.

Comment: @MattDMo I was not bitching, I don't understand why you would see my criticism in that way, all I was saying is that I wish that sublime was more active because it is my favorite text editor, anyway I wish you the best.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [Linode](https://www.linode.com/), Package Control's hosting provider, has been under a [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack since [Dec. 25](http://status.linode.com/). You can monitor [@linode](https://twitter.com/linode) on Twitter for news, and [@wbond](https://twitter.com/wbond) for Package Control updates.

For now I **wouldn't** recommend using the workaround suggested in other answers, as fixing it when Package Control is back up and running will be a pain, and ultimately some will forget to and never get updated packages again.